# I want a way to manage relation between 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables. Drummer and DrummerType.

```
DRUMMER_TYPE 
ID      TYPE
1       A1
2       A2
3       A3

DRUMMER
ID     NAME    TYPE
1      A       1
2      B       2
3      C       1
```

I want a way to add more type's to drummer. I don't want to add a new table and maintain relation cause on drummer table already done too much coding. Is there any way that I can maintain the relation (not using comma separated)?

For comma separated it will look like this (i don't want like this is there any other way):

```
DRUMMER
ID    NAME    TYPE
1     A       1,2,3  
2     B       2,3
3     C       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes The Design should be :

```
Two tables :

1) Drummers     : id, name, type
2) Drummer_type : id, desc

The Drummers.type will be a reference to Drummer_type.id

Now IF you want to add more drummer's type, just insert a row in Drummer_type table
```

Please let me know if you have any doubt regarding this.

Comment: Thanks, they are already related. I have edited the question i want something that will replace the comma-separated way to manage the relation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bitwise field, more info: http://home.comcast.net/~tolkin.family/bitwise.htm

For example you can code your three DRUMMER_TYPE this manner:

```
000 = Nothing
001 = A1
010 = A2
100 = A3
```

This way if you can save DRUMMER_TYPE A1 and A3 for a DRUMMER, you can save the value `101` in the database. The technique is similar to the way permissions works on an unix system.

Comment: I don't think it for multiple value's.

Comment: @VivekMuthal, I don't understand you, you are asking: "I want a way to add more type's to drummer". I'm confused.

Comment: And you join this to the Drummer Type table how?

Comment: I want drummer A to use two drum types A1,A2 as show in comma separated table.

Comment: Ok, @JamesAnderson, you're correct, this way you can't use the other table, you need to code the different states. Perhaps is more suitable for static states than't don't change too often.

Comment: Right, And my problem is the values will not be static and also one drummer can be able to play any type of drum and whenever want can remove that instrument so not only storing but whole CRUD needs to be easily operable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a many to many relationship then you should have a third table to maintain that relationship:

```
DrummerIs:  DrummerId, TypeId
```

There are other ways of doing this (multiple columns, concatenated values etc.) but they all have serious pitfalls. Using a relationship table to maintain a many to many relationship is nearly always recommended because in the end it is the simplest to implement and use.

Comment: I don't have many to many relation. And don't want third table i know that will be the last option for me but still waiting if someone knows any other technique. And you are right multiple columns, concatenated values etc all have serious pitfalls.

Comment: You have a one to many relationship. One drummer can have many skills. Just add a relationship table to model this -- it really is the easiest way.

Comment: I forgot about it Thanks. Now i am trying this sql command "ALTER TABLE drummer ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY fk_type ( type ) references drummer_type(ID)" and getting errno(150) can't create table. I am searching for answer but it will be great help if you know why this error is coming.